# how do I make a good subquery in SQL in this code

Tags: sql, count, where-clause

I need a bit of help with an SQL statement, pretty much a beginner so just go easy on me.

The Program want me to give out every Student who studied for less than 7 years at a School

```
Select schoolid, characterid, firstname, lastname, count(year) as num
from schoolhouse natural join student natural join character
group by schoolid, characterid, firstname, lastname
```

So far, so good, with this code I can already see a relation with the counted years but I can't make a where statement which includes the "num" count from the select statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WHERE` clauses are applied to the individual rows after the tables are joined, but before they are grouped/aggregated.  `HAVING` clauses are used to assert conditions on the results of the aggregation.  Just add `HAVING count(year) < 7`

```
Select schoolid, characterid, firstname, lastname, count(year) as num
from schoolhouse natural join student natural join character
group by schoolid, characterid, firstname, lastname
having count(year) < 7
```

But also ***always*** qualify which table your columns come from.  In this query it's not clear if the `year` column is from the `schoolhouse` table, the `student` table or the `character` table.

It should look more like...

```
SELECT TABLE.schoolid, TABLE.characterid, TABLE.firstname, TABLE.lastname, COUNT(TABLE.year) AS num
FROM schoolhouse NATURAL JOIN student NATURAL JOIN character
GROUP BY TABLE.schoolid, TABLE.characterid, TABLE.firstname, TABLE.lastname
HAVING COUNT(TABLE.year) < 7
```

*(Replacing each occurance of `TABLE` with the correct table name for each case.)*

Finally, using words such as `character` and `year` as column or table names is usually frowned upon.  Such words ofter appear as "key-words" in SQL and can cause errors or ambiguity.  In general, if something even ***might*** appear as an SQL key-word, don't use it as a column or table name.

Comment: @DavidRumpf - Feel free to upvote and/or accept any answers that help you.